# Laravel: Select teams and count each team members

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two tables: 'teams' and 'team_members',

```
Table : 'teams'
 __________________
| id |   name     |
|-----------------|
| 1 |    t1       |
| 2 |    t2       |
| 3 |    t3       |
|-----------------|

table : team_members
 _______________________________
| id |     team_id  |  user_id  |
|-------------------------------|
|  1 |      1       |    2      |
|  2 |      1       |    2      |
|  3 |      2       |    1      |
|  4 |      2       |    1      |
|  5 |      2       |    1      |
|-------------------|------------
```

How can I get all teams and the number of members on each team like :

team `t1` has 2 members.

team `t2` has 3 members.

What I have tried is (not working and gets only one team with number of members) :

```
SELECT teams.name, count(O.team_id) 
as total FROM teams 
LEFT JOIN 
team_members as O 
ON 
O.team_id = teams.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using group by it's solved.
Here is the query.

```
SELECT teams.name, COUNT(o.team_id) 
AS total FROM teams 
LEFT JOIN 
team_members AS o
ON 
o.team_id = teams.id
GROUP BY o.team_id
```